# SMARTCTL Reallocated_Sector_Ct attribute meaning

Tags: smartctl

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  ...
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
```

Does the `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` metric mean the available count of sectors or does it mean the current used RS count and the whole metric says that the threshold has been arrived?

Comment: "_Does it mean the current used reallocated sector count?_", right, it is the count of sectors which became reallocated.

Comment: Did you take a look at the Wikipedia page for [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology) that gives a good explanation for that particular metric and the others

Answer (score 0):

As I already commented, the Wikipedia page for [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology) has quite a bit to say about S.M.A.R.T. attributes in general and the "Reallocated Sectors Count" attribute in particular:

> The following chart lists some S.M.A.R.T. attributes and the typical meaning of their **raw values**. **Normalized values** are usually mapped so that higher values are better (exceptions include drive temperature, number of head load/unload cycles[26]), but higher raw attribute values may be better or worse depending on the attribute and manufacturer. ***For example, the "Reallocated Sectors Count" attribute's normalized value decreases as the count of reallocated sectors increases. In this case, the attribute's raw value will often indicate the actual count of sectors that were reallocated,*** although vendors are in no way required to adhere to this convention.
>
> | attribute | Ideal (raw value) | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Reallocated Sectors Count | low (i.e. zero is best) | Count of reallocated sectors. The raw value represents a count of the bad sectors that have been found and remapped.[32] Thus, the higher the attribute value, the more sectors the drive has had to reallocate. This value is primarily used as a metric of the life expectancy of the drive; a drive which has had any reallocations at all is significantly more likely to fail in the immediate months |

So in your case that means:

| ATTRIBUTE_NAME | VALUE (the *normalized* value) | WORST | THRESH | TYPE | UPDATED | WHEN_FAILED | RAW_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Reallocated_Sector_Ct | 100 | 100 | 005 | Pre-fail | Always | - | 0 |
| *my* explanantion: | `100` is the common initial value , so this looks OK, This normalized value decreases as the count of reallocated sectors increases. |  | the threshold value below which the normalized `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` attribute value should not fall |  |  |  | 0 = no reallocated sectors, your drive is completely healthy in this regard. This value will increase with each reallocated sector. |